# Is it possible to get the app instances subscribe on a topic with GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Does an API exist to get the APP instances who are in a topic ?

Answer (score 0):

On [Role of the Application Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server), there is no service for getting registration ids which are registered to GCM or registered in a topic.

So you have to implement your own server and record registration_ids and topics in a database.